# ExtJS Button is not shown

Tags: extjs

Why is the button not shown in this example?

```
var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'My Test Button',
    listeners: {
        click: function (button, e, options) {
            alert(this.text);
        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
button.show();
```

Comment: The API docs for 4.2.2 show `handler:` rather than `listeners:` for click.  Perhaps this is the issue?  Do you get any errors in your console?  Does the button get written to the DOM but not rendered on the screen?

Comment: You'll also want to use `'Ext.Button'` rather than `'Ext.button.Button'` [API Link](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.button.Button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you wrap it in the onReady() function?

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
var button = Ext.create('Ext.button.Button', {
    text: 'My Test Button',
    listeners: {
        click: function (button, e, options) {
            alert(this.text);
        }
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
button.show();

});
```

Comment: Just forgot the wrapper. Thanks a lot.